# Error when Connection remote mysql database using jpa in Springboot spring boot 1 5 10 RELEASE

Tags: spring-boot

I'm getting the following error when making a connection to remote mysql database using jpa in Springboot spring boot 1 5 10 RELEASE.

Why am I getting this error?

```
Parameter 0 of constructor in org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration required a bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' that could not be found.
    - Bean method 'dataSource' not loaded because @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseType'
    - Bean method 'dataSource' not loaded because @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseType'
```

Action:

```
Consider revisiting the conditions above or defining a bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' in your configuration.
```

Comment: show your configuration also

Comment: And please add your POM